# how to know the liquibase changesets are safe enough to run on a database

Tags: database, upgrade, liquibase

I am trying to develop a web application that upgrades user's database according to the application version the user chooses.I am using liquibase api to do this.Each version has a set of liquibase changeset files. I want to make sure that the changesets that are to be run on user's db are safe. is there any way to verify the changesets against user's db without effecting the db and then update liquibase files? My changesets don't have "rollback" tags.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21847482/does-liquibase-support-dry-run

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preConditions` for it.
Besides built-in preConditions, of which there are many, there's a `sqlCheck`, that allows you to check any condition you want. You can check for possible errors and inconsistencies in `sqlCheck` precondition.

```
<changeSet id="changesetId" author="changesetAuthor">
        <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
            <sqlCheck expectedResult="">
                <!-- your SQL here -->
            </sqlCheck>
        </preConditions>
        <!-- the rest of the changeSet -->
```

Check out the liquibase docs for [preConditions](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/preconditions.html).

Comment: tnx for d reply. i am dealing wid a large no.of changesets . i want to avoid editing them."safe" in dis context means the changesets of a version should either be executed completely or not at all but not partially. upgrading process is sequential ,an error at middle stops the process leaving user's db incomplete .is there a way to know the error before hand? I tried transaction management to rollback when an error occurs but the ddl statements are forcing implicit commit.

Comment: well, if a user already has a database, then this database already has the changesets rolled, and this database has respective records in `databasechangelog` table, so they won't be executed again. So you need new changeSets to alter the existing database, don't you? So `sqlCheck` could do the trick. Or am I missing something?

Comment: yes , absolutely i can use databasechangelog table  to continue from where i left.This is exactly how our existing upgrade application works. The application now i am developing demands a verification execution  before applying changes to user's db.The following eg might help better understanding.  user's version : 1.0 - available upgrade version : 4.0 . To upgrade, the application must run all the sets in 2.0 ,3.0,4.0 .lets suppose an error occurred at 7th set in 3.0 then the application should make db 2.0 but not 2.0 and 6 sets of 3.0.

Comment: the changesets are robust(no need to change). if any error occurs that might be from user's db .

Comment: Now that's getting bit tricky. I think it's beyond my expertise, sorry. Only thing that comes to mind is to somehow wrap the changesets from versions 2,3 and 4 into one big changeset or try to use transaction manager, catch the exception and roll back the changes manually

Comment: This is probably not something you want to hear, but you could look at Datical DB (a commercial offering that uses Liquibase internally) as we have implemented a Forecast feature that simulates the changes to be made before actually applying them. Implementing the forecast functionality was not a trivial exercise.